# Set the UDP/TCP checksum to null on PcapDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, packet, pcap.net

I using this project DLLs and after change IP Address:

```
private Packet ChangePacketIp(Packet packet, IpV4Address oldIpAddress, IpV4Address newIpAddress)
{
    try
    {
        EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
        IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
        IpV4Datagram ipV4Datagram = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
        ILayer layer = ipV4Datagram.ExtractLayer();
        DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
        ILayer payload = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer();
        if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Source == oldIpAddress)
        {
            ipV4Layer.Source = newIpAddress;
            ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
        }
        else if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Destination == oldIpAddress)
        {
            ipV4Layer.CurrentDestination = newIpAddress;
            ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
        }

        return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, payload);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to set the UDP/TCP checksum to null before building the packet so  try;

```
packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Checksum = null;
```

But ushort is a non nullable value type, any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/349978 try this:

```
    //IP
    IpV4Layer ipLayer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
    ipLayer.HeaderChecksum = null;

    //TCP
    TransportLayer transportLayer = (TransportLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.ExtractLayer();
    transportLayer.Checksum = null;

    //UDP
    UdpLayer udpLayer = (UdpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Udp.ExtractLayer();
    udpLayer.Checksum = null;
```

Comment: That also for TCP and UDP ?

Comment: BTW if i change only the Port or only the MAC Address i still need to calculate this too ?

Comment: If you set it to null, it will be calculated by the network card I think. The MAC address is Layer 2(i.e. the Ethernet frame that carries IP so it does not affect the checksum), the port is not used for the cheksum as per: http://www.daemon.org/tcp.html#sum

Comment: OK and when building this packet (see my code) i need to put also this 2 layers ? (what order ?)

Comment: Before PacketBuilder.Build, i would remove it from the if and just write:
TransportLayer transportLayer = (TransportLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.ExtractLayer();
    transportLayer.Checksum = null;
IpV4Layer ipLayer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
    ipLayer.HeaderChecksum = null;

Comment: But i think while building the packet i need to put transportLayer in the constructor but in where ?

Comment: there should be an overload that accepts the tcp part `PacketBuilder.Build(DateTime.Now, ethernet, ipLayer, tcpLayer, payload);`

Comment: But what if this is an UDP packet ?

Comment: then I suppose you'll have to check. `if (transportLayer == null)` and `if(udpLayer == null)`

Comment: Are you sure i need to use udpLayer ? i think transportLayer is enough because in this way you don't need to know in advanced if it is TCP or UDP

Comment: you can't know, it can be either tcp or udp or icmp that's why I suppose you can check the type of the packet and act accordingly.